# Database changes not propagating to entity model

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using EF5 with C# and SQL Server 2012. We're using database first. I made some changes to the database, added a couple views and a few table columns.

When I go into the edmx file in Visual Studio 2012 and select Update Model From Database everything is shown in the model view. The new views are present as well as the new fields.

But none of the new elements propagate into the auto generated model.cs file. I've updated the model from the database multiple times and rebuilt the solution many times as well.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-Click on the tt-files (one for the dbcontext, and one for the containers) that is connected to your edmx-file. Click "run custom tool". This will rebuild your containers